# PHP : Amazon ses api . SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): Sender - RequestExpired: Request timestamp:

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While i am trying to send mails from my local server i got the following error message .

```
Warning:  SimpleEmailService::sendEmail(): Sender - RequestExpired: Request timestamp: Thu, 13 Mar 2014 06:22:22 UTC expired.  It must be within 300 secs/ of server time.
Request Id: 1ceb9cf2-aa77-11e3-808a-65eb63aafe5e
 in xxx.\php-ses\ses.php on line 362
```

I got a solution from http://www.conandalton.net/2011/02/aws-ses-requestexpired.html . But I still gettinf the same error . Give me a suitable solution

Comment: When you tried what's mentioned in the post you link (essentially, setting your own server clock correctly) did you verify that your server clock time did change, and that the clock is indeed now set correctly?

Comment: Setting server clock time correctly works for me, thanks.